# Is this database relationship circular and is it appropriate to do

Tags: mysql, database, relationship

I am creating a hotel managment database and i've come up with this problem when designing database.
One hotel has many rooms, so relationship between them is 1:n, also one hotel has many reservations so relatioship between them is also 1:n, but i am not sure whether to make relationship between rooms and reservations 1:1, since one room can have one reservation at a time or to make that relationship n:m since many rooms can have many reservations through time, or is that relationship even necessary to exist
[here is the photo]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXnNU.png

Comment: A room can't be reserved in advance? Like room 42 is reserved by X in january and by Y in February? n:m sounds the way to go

Comment: by the way, there shouldn't be any hotel -> reservation relation, it makes no sense, you don't reserve an hotel but a room.

Comment: @Cid yep i agree with that hotel => reservation relation, that was my first thought on this, but than i overthinked it a little, should've sticked with it from start

Comment: Might be better posted on sister site, https://DBA.StackExchange.com.